# a question concerning multiplication of cardinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider $\{B_i\}$ where $i\in I$ and $I$ is countable infinite. $|B_i|=|B_j|=n$ for all $i,j$ and $n \ge |\mathbb{N}|$. I want to show that $| \large \cup_{i\in I}$$B_i|=n$

I am given that $a*a=a$ for any infinite cardinal $a$ and I know that $|\mathbb{N}^k|=|\mathbb{N}|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** First show that in the case that the $B_i$ are pairwise disjoint, the union embeds into $n\times\Bbb N$. Then show that in the case it's not disjoint you can still embed it, with a slight twist. Then use what you are given.

---

Find an injection from $\bigcup B_i$ into $I\times B$, where $B$ is any set of cardinality $n$. Since $I$ is countable we can assume that $I=\Bbb N$.

Next find an injection from $B$ into $\Bbb N\times B$; and an injection from $\Bbb N\times B$ into $B\times B$. Now use the fact that $B\times B$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: I have that any infinite set can be written as the union of two disjoint sets with the same cardinality. So then may I assume they are disjoint without loss of generality because we would still have a countable infinite index.

Comment: So I am still stuck on this, could you explain a little more @asafkaragila

Comment: Ahh ok I think I get the idea. So since $B$ is the same size as each $B_i$ there is a bijection from each of the $B_i$ to $B$, call it $f_i$, then we can have an injection  $g:\large \cup B_i\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\times B$, $g(x)=(i,f_i(x))$ where $x\in B_i$. Am I going about this in the best way?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I am sorry, but I think I should have also told you that I have a theorem that says if $c$ and $d$ are infinite cardinalities and $c\le d$ then $cd=d$. So I think really I would be done?

Comment: I think this is the second time you have easily helped me with my set theory class. Can you come teach or Tudor us? jk im sure you are plenty busy. thank you.

Comment: I'm already TA'ing a set theory class. So you'll have to come to me, I'm afraid. The professor is a world renowned set theorist, so that's another bonus. You'll have to learn Hebrew for it, though.

Comment: My wife's family would love that. They are constantly joking with me to convert :) So cool that you get to work with someone who loves it( and you obviously do). This is my first time with set theory. I love abstract algebra so I am auditing this class just to see if I like it, and now I wish I would have enrolled; I really like it so far.

Comment: Well, good luck, then.

Comment: I now see the problem if my sets are not pairwise disjoint. Is the trick you are referring to something like a map between $B_i$ and $B_i \times \{i\}$ then these will be pairwise disjoint and obviously have the same cardinal number. And now I use the obvious map $g$ from $\large \cup (B_i \times \{i\}) $ to $\mathbb{N} \times B$. $g((x,i))=(i, f_i(x))$ Then this map will be a bijection.

Does this properly deal with the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is an option, but you can instead map each $x\in\bigcup B_i$ to a unique $(f_i(x),i)$. You just need to choose the right $i$ for the task. The rest of the proof stays the same.

Comment: Great. love the freedom!